# how do I select a url parameter?

Tags: php

So I have a backoffice called `biblioteca.php` where I have some requests and I can validate them trough a button called "Validar". That button redirects to a page like this: `http://localhost/pap_16gpsi21/validacao.php?nproposta=87` where I can fill the form and submit.

What I want is to validate the request related to that url.

Example:

I've a request and his number is 90, I click on "Validar", then redirects me to a page like this `http://localhost/pap_16gpsi21/validacao.php?nproposta=90`, I fill the form and click submit. Then it updates the request number 90 in the database (`$updateEstado = "UPDATE propostas SET validacao='Validado'";`)

> biblioteca.php

```
$selectProp = "SELECT nproposta, prioridade,disponibilidade,validacao,
                      autorizacao,aquisicao,registo,biblioteca,docente 
                FROM propostas 
                ORDER BY nproposta DESC";

$resultado = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $selectProp);

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

<td><a class="btn btn-default" href="./validacao.php?nproposta=<?= $row["nproposta"] ?>">Validar</a></td>
```

> valida.php

```
// gets nproposta from propostas
$npropostaLinha = "SELECT nproposta FROM propostas";
$resultado=mysqli_query($ligaBD, $npropostaLinha);
$nproposta = "";
printf($npropostaLinha);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado,MYSQLI_NUM);
printf("==> ");
print_r($row[0]);
$nproposta = $row[0];   

$insertValidacao = "INSERT INTO validacao 
                            (nproposta,nome_validacao,nif_validacao,
                              email_validacao,preco_validacao) 
            VALUES ($nproposta,'$nome_validacao','$nif_validacao',
                   '$email_validacao','$preco_validacao')"; 

$updateEstado = "UPDATE propostas SET validacao='Validado'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $insertValidacao);

$resultado = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $updateEstado);
```

The problem is that if I have 3 requests (90,91,92) and I decide to validate just the number 91 it updates the first which is the number 90.

Also I know this isnt the safest method but this is just a test.

Hopefully, I explained explicitly. Sorry for any grammatical mistakes. Thank you

Comment: What variable do you use to specify to the script that its the `91` you wish to target and not the `90`? With that variable you can add a `WHERE` clause to your `SELECT` query. Also, when you are updating the validation, your UPDATE query is updating every single row in your DB

Comment: That's what I'm trying to know. I've tried that using the method $_GET but it didnt work. Obrigado

Comment: If you submit the form, add a hidden field with the `nproposta` within the form, so you can access the variable.  It helps if you post in your question the form itself :)

Comment: If you're talking about this (http://prntscr.com/nmgqft) I already had it :/

Comment: That is a query, I am looking for `<form action="" method="">` view

Comment: I added an answer because I believe I understand what is happening in the script. Although, would be nice if the `<form>` view could be added to confirm my idea :) Hopefully helps! Otherwise I will take it down due to misunderstanding and go to the shame corner x')

Comment: This is my form http://prntscr.com/nmgwkw

Comment: would you mind checking my answer and let me know if it work for you? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a couple of changes in your code as there are a few  logical mistakes that I think you want to avoid.

1. You need to target a variable to specify from your `SELECT` that you desire a specific `proposta`;
2. You need, when updating, to specify which row, otherwise you will update every single record in your DB;

For such, go to your `valida.php` and add the following:

**At the very top, check you have the variable ready**

```
if (!isset($_POST['nproposta']) || empty($_POST['nproposta'])) {
    //Do here what you desire to stop the script from running. Redirect back if you wish;
    echo "No proposal id was found";
    die;
}

$nPropostaID = $_POST['nproposta'];
```

Once you have your ID to target the row in your DB, update your query to consider it;

`UPDATE propostas SET validacao='Validado' WHERE nproposta = $nPropostaID`

**Go to your form view and add below line within the form**

```
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $_GET['nproposta']?>" name="nproposta">
```

**NOTE:** Because you mentioned you are aware of the SQL injections and this is a test I won't go with those, but always good to remember to be careful with them :) My proposal for the queries is just to get you going and in no way good for a script!